# check if password_hash exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

Now we know `password_hash` exist on in PHP version 5.5 and above.

**So what if the server we are using have older version of PHP?**

For that I want to create a condition if function `password_hash` exist or not.

**I am checking it like this:**

```
if(function_exists('password_hash')){
    //do nothing
} else {
    // code of password_hash and password_verify
}
```

I am getting code from [**here**](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).

So this check is for community.

I am using this in codeigniter helper when i run this it stop `password_hash` function and display nothing.

tell me where I am going wrong and how can i do it better way!

Comment: Just include provided file by yourself without any condition.

Comment: `if(!function_exists('password_hash')` maybe, its had to understand your question

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use this piece of code for checking that is there `function password_hash` exists or not:

```
if(!function_exists('password_hash')){
   // Not Present hash function
}
else{
  // Present function
}
```

Comment: my code is working fine in core php but i was asking in view of codeigniter but thank for help!

Comment: Oh!! I didn't noticed that.